# load all images from sdcard folder to imageview one by one using handler but is showing only one image

Tags: android, imageview, handler, android-sdcard

I am trying load image one by one from sdcard folder images and using handler after few seconds they automatically change but does not change other image is showing only one image

Here I put my handler code for get and set image on create activity

> HomeActivity.java

```
final Handler imagehandler = new Handler();

                    Runnable runnable;

                    runnable = new Runnable()
                    {

                        int i=0;
                        @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
                        public void run()
                        {   // slider image run




                            File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/images/");
                            File file[]=dir.listFiles();

                            for (int i=0;i<file.length;i++)
                            {

                                Drawable d = (Drawable) Drawable.createFromPath(file[i].toString());
                                imageslider.setImageDrawable(d);
                                imagehandler.postDelayed(this, 4000);



                          // for interval
                        }

                    };
                    imagehandler.postDelayed(runnable,10);
           }
```

Comment: make your i value global

Comment: thanks you are right i was setted every time  0 so is take only one image thanks for help thankssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: Better examples of loading images is [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/),its actually with lazy loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove for loop from Runnable before this will show always last image in imageView . instead of for loop use a counter for showing images like :

```
 File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/images/");
 File file[]=dir.listFiles();

public static int count=0;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                     if(count<file.length){

                       Drawable d = (Drawable) 
                           Drawable.createFromPath(file[count].toString());

                       imageslider.setImageDrawable(d);

                        count++;  //<<< increment counter here
                     }
                    else{
                          // reset counter here
                          count=0;
                     }

                }
            }, 4000);
```

Comment: yes right hey is solved but i want to give the effect like in this website main banner  http://digitalhoteladnetwork.com/vixxa_beta/index.php  left side big image is load i want to give the effect like this how can i give this type of effect in android

Comment: @androidmania : if it's working then good but if you use for loop it. u can also try my suggestion before this will work without for loop

Comment: if(i>file.length-1)
                          {
                  i=0;  
                       }
                 Drawable d = (Drawable) Drawable.createFromPath(file[i].toString());
                 imageslider.setImageDrawable(d);
                 imagehandler.postDelayed(this, 4000);
                 i++;  i use this code thanks your code is also work

Comment: http://digitalhoteladnetwork.com/vixxa_beta/index.php i want to give the effect like in this website you can see in website left side image one by one change with the different effect how to give this effect

Comment: @androidmania : for this type of effects you will need to use Android Animation api's